# Razorsharp, C# + HTML: Combo box that you can also type a custom string input into

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor

I'm working in a cshtml file. I'm trying to filter based on what a user types into a text box, but I also want a dropdown box with options to select from too. Right now I only have a textbox that a user can enter text into and filter by, but no dropdown with options to it. Is there a different element I can use that can add the dropdownlist option along with the entering text option too?
My code right now
`@Html.TextBox("RoomName", "", new { @class = "form-control" })`
I would like for it to be able to keep the same name, and be a similar type of input if possible so that it continues working with my other functionality. Let me know if this exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `datalist`.Here is a demo:

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Edge">Edge</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
    <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
    <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
    <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
</datalist>
```

result:
[image]